# Mac On-screen Keyboard + Shortcuts

Tags: mac, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I need to (via logmein) remotely send a keyboard shortcut to a mac.  The program I'm trying to use doesn't seem to recognize the keystrokes via logmein.  I'm trying to use the mac on screen keyboard to accomplish this (called the "keyboard viewer"), but I can't figure out how to hold down multiple keys at once.  Does anybody else know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around this another way.... don't think there is anything out there that will let you do this.

Comment: Well, why didn't you answer how you actually did it? And, as a guide line, you should leave it as "unaccepted" if it didn't answer your question... But you could leave it as accepted if it fixed your issue. ;)